# Community Guest User vs Force.com Guest Site User

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, community, force.com-sites, lightning-community

What is the difference between community guest user and Force.com site guest user?

Primarily based on the number of views.  Is there any limitation on concurrency or guest page loads or view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both contexts there are limitations (albeit high). In both contexts the limitations are a function of the Salesforce editions. Also, as a heads up, there are limitations beyond the # of page views.

In a site context, there are limitations in terms of

- Bandwidth Allocation(PER ROLLING 24-HOUR PERIOD PER SITE)
- Service Request Time (PER ROLLING 24-HOUR PERIOD PER SITE)
- Max Page Views

This [sites documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_limits.htm&type=5) will tell you about the Limitations, Billing and Monthly Page Views Enforcement, What Counts as a Page View, and how to Monitor Usage. To your question, Enterprise Edition Orgs get 500,000 views, and Unlimited Edition get One million.

Likewise, there are limitations around Community Guest Licences. Again, the page view limitation is a function of the SF edition you have, where overages are calculated on a yearly basis. Enterprise Edition Orgs get 500,000/month, and Unlimited Edition get One million/month.  Here is the similar [communities documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5)

In any case, to track your view usage, check out this free app on the app exchange. This package gives you reports and a dashboard to monitor usage of your Force.com sites. Analyze monthly page views, daily bandwidth, and daily request time to avoid reaching monthly and daily limits for individual sites and your organization. - https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001SUEwEAO